# Best practices using process builder and flows

Tags: process-builder, flow

I want to know the best practices of using process builder and flows.

I have a problem statement like, based on recordType and other field selection different types of updates (field updates) and scheduled actions need to be performed.

Now there are 5 different recordtypes exist and for each recordtype separate processes have been defined in process builder.

For each processes of single recordtype, based on field values there are more than 15 criteria have been defined and for each criteria there are separate field updates and scheduled actions.

As I know if any update is performed on a record, system will check each processes and for each processes it will check each criteria for matching, which is often a performance overhead.

Is there any kind of method of elimination can be performed based on recordtype selection of each processes. Do we need to use flow (which will get called from process builder) where it will use the criteria logic and do the field update and scheduled action?

Thanks to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following guideline, provided by salesforce:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_considerations_design_bestpractices.htm&type=5